# not able to print variable a in c++

Tags: c++, global-variables

```
#include<iostream.h>

int a;
class g{      
    cout<<a;
};

int main()
{
    cout<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Why am I not able to print the global variable `a` inside of the class, but at same time, I am able to print `a` inside `main`? Is there no way to use `cout` in a class?

Comment: you can not execute in class declarations.

Comment: you should read up on the syntax of class declarations, you need to create a method in the class that does what you want

Comment: "Don't read after this" - Are you missing a backspace and delete key?

Comment: @user1810087 so can i put main in a class and print that like in java?

Comment: @chris i was not able to post this question as stackoverflow was asking more details for this question

Comment: no you have to create a function and call it.

Comment: Do keep in mind `iostream.h` is not a standard header. Use `iostream`.

Comment: You are writing C++, not Java. Please read basic C++ beginner book first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot write a statement like that in the middle of a class, it is essentially like doing

```
struct g
{
  cout << a;
};
```

which makes no sense, instead define a method in g in this case a static one would do since your variable is anyway global.

```
int a;
class g
{
public:
  static void printA()
  {
    cout<<a;
  }
};

// now you can print a

int main()
{
 cout<<a;
 g::printA();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: in c++ any variables declared inside a class are also global variables like in java?

Comment: @user3690061, What? There are no variables declared in a class here, and they are most certainly not global in Java.

Comment: @chris what if i declare a variable in a class? what do you call that variable ,as in java they are called instance variable

Comment: @user3690061 declared variables in a c++ class are instance variables (if they are not declared static)

Comment: @user3690061 i would suggest taking a look at http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html

Comment: @user3690061, Data members would be a more appropriate C++ terminology, but same thing, really.

Comment: @Claptrap so if they are declared public static like in java they would be called as global variable ?

Comment: @user3690061 yes, if the variable in the class is declared static then you can access it by prefixing with the class name since it is not an instance variable otherwise you need to create an instance of the class and access it via the instance

Comment: @Claptrap my intentions are not to learn c++, i just want clarify the meaning of global variables with respect to c++ and java ,i am confused about global variables in java whether they exist in java or not ,i have posted a question regarding this hava a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060921/is-there-anything-called-global-variable-in-java