# Android WeakReference

Tags: android, weak-references

I have an activity where i have to trigger from place to place a custom pop-up dialog which is also a singleton

From my activity i open the pop-up :

```
  ScheduleDialog.getInstance().refreshContent(new WeakReference<Context>(this), new WeakReference<ScheduleDialog.interface>(this));
```

What is best ?
1) create 2 local references ( in ScheduleDialog ) like :

```
   Context mContext = nContext.get();
```

2) keep both like weak reference and only when i need them use :

```
nContext.get();
```

This is related about leaks error/warnings

Thanks

Comment: You did not explain why you are using `WeakReference` for context (if in fact you can use Application context) and also show the ScheduleDialog code (otherwise we do not know if your code is leaky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I see your code you create strong reference again after get weak reference value in `Context nContext` variable. So need to follow below process if you want to implement weak reference concept :-

define global class variable :-

```
private final WeakReference< Context > nContext;
```

set value in global variable through passing from another area

```
nContext = new WeakReference<Context>(nContext);
```

and then

```
if (nContext.get() != null) 
    // code
}
```

https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/weakreference-in-android-dd1e66b9be9d

Comment: I think you mean `member variable` cuz we [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581234/why-are-there-no-global-variables-in-java) have global variable in Java.

Comment: so you are pointing on the second option but with a little update : ScheduleDialog.getInstance().refreshContent(this,this)  with the help of your  article. Right ?

Comment: @user863873 honestly I don't see the point of using WeakReference not unless your dialog can outlive your view like for example how Thread does (that's the only case you worry for leak).

Comment: i see your point. May be is a dummy question but : what if i have multiple activities and each one has recyclerview + adapter. If i use weakreference in each adapter if there will be memory problem ... only the adapter(s) will be GC.  Or this is not possible because adapter is a member variable in activity and if memory problem also the activity will be GC ?

Comment: @user863873 if your activity is destroyed your Adapter and RecyclerView will also be Garbage collected (since your activity is the only the one holding the reference to them not unless a *static* reference is holding them or a background Thread itself). You could experiment this using [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary).

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep them as WeakReferences, otherwise the Garbage Collector will see there are strong references to the object and won't collect them, leading to the leak you mentioned.